# what is the Mechanize get_link equivalent in mechanicalsoup?

Tags: python, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to write a code which will read the name of a movie and try to get details of it from IMDB using python 3.0. I am using mechanicalsoup but after opening the browser there is no way of getting link of the movies. In mechanize there was a method named get_link and follow_link. Is there any equivalent to this in mechanicalsoup.
The code is as follows.

```
import mechanicalsoup
import re
def main():
    movie='The Incredibles';
    base_url='http://www.imdb.com/find?q=';
    movie_search='+'.join(movie.split());
    final_url=base_url+movie_search+'&s=all';
    br=mechanicalsoup.Browser();
    br.get(final_url);
    link=br.find_link(url_regex=re.compile(r'/title/tt.*'));
    res=br.follow_link(link);
    soup=mechanicalsoup(res.read());
    print(soup.prettify());

if __name__=="__main__":main()
```

Here I am getting the error

```
"AttributeError: 'Browser' object has no attribute 'find_link'"
```

Please help me out. Also suggest if there are any better html parsers in python with updated documentation.

Comment: Bump. I'm having the same issue. Any ideas?